# Highcharts: how to align items in legend with multiple rows to the right

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart that has a horizontal legend with items in multiple rows. The legend box is aligned to the right, but the items inside are aligned to the left. How can I get the items to align right as well?

Here is a fiddle of my current chart: http://jsfiddle.net/vgkcgxe4/
Fiddle HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Fiddle CSS:

```
@import 'https://code.highcharts.com/css/highcharts.css';
#container {
  height: 400px;
  max-width: 800px;
  min-width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Fiddle JS:

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    title: "",
    chart: {
      spacing: [5, 5, 5, 5],
      marginLeft: 32,
      type: "column"
    },
    legend: {
      align: "right",
      verticalAlign: "top",
      itemDistance: 15,
      symbolHeight: 8,
      symbolPadding: 0,
      padding: 0,
      margin: 20,
      itemMarginBottom: 5,
      width: 375
    },
    series: [{
      name: "First",
      data: [8, 10, 8, 12],
    }, {
      name: "Second",
      data: [13, 11, 11, 3]
    }, {
      name: "Third",
      data: [9, 9, 9, 9]
    }, {
      name: "Fourth",
      data: [9, 12, 9, 6]
    }, {
      name: "Fifth",
      data: [13, 6, 5, 11]
    }, {
      name: "Sixth",
      data: [10, 6, 6, 7]
    }, {
      name: "Seventh",
      data: [4, 9, 5, 8]
    }, {
      name: "Eighth",
      data: [9, 7, 2, 8]
    }],
    yAxis: {
      visible: true,
      reversedStacks: false,
      tickPosition: "inside",
      offset: 0,
      type: "linear",
      title: {
        text: "axis title",
        align: "high",
        textAlign: "left",
        rotation: 0,
        offset: 0,
        margin: 0,
        y: -5,
        x: -7
      },
      labels: {
        align: "right",
        y: -5
      },
      tickPositions: [0, 6, 12, 18]
    },
    xAxis: {
      labels: {
        y: 16
      },
      categories: ["2016 Jul", "2016 Aug", "2016 Sep", "2016 Oct"]
    }
  });
});
```

Here is an image of how I would like the items to be: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVVeR.png)
I have tried using "useHTML" on the legend, but the items remain absolutely positioned.

Comment: I don't think it is possible without re-position the legend manually. So one way is to re-position svg items, creating your own HTML legend (which might be easier than re-positioning the existing one). There is also option rtl but it also reverses symbols.http://jsfiddle.net/vgkcgxe4/2/